# Using a Python logger SocketHandler to log directly into carbon (graphite)?

Tags: python, graphite

I did my best to log metrics directly into carbon through SocketHandler with no luck:

`logger.conf`:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,carbon

[handlers]
keys=carbonHandler

[formatters]
keys=carbonFormatter

[logger_carbon]
level=DEBUG
handlers=carbonHandler
qualname=carbon
propagate=0

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=carbonHandler

[handler_carbonHandler]
class=logging.handlers.SocketHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=carbonFormatter
args=('$HOST', 2003)

[formatter_carbonFormatter]
format=%(message)s %(created)i
```

And then, tying to log with it:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

logger = logging.getLogger('carbon')
logger.info('test.python 42')
```

And this is a sad fail...

I can talk to carbon using `echo "test.metric 42 $(date +'%s')" | nc $HOST 2003`

Do you see anything?

Do I try to do something that won't ever work?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: let's say I'm dumb, and this can't be done this way.

A standard socket write to carbon with full efficiency:

    import socket, time
    s = socket.create_connection((HOST, PORT))
    s.send('test.testpython 42 %i\n'%time.time())
    s.close()

end you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your config file is exactly as is - replace "$HOST" in your config file with the actual name of the host. What happens then? If that works and you need the name to be environment-dependent, try using

```
args=(os.environ['HOST'], 2003)
```

in the config file.